# Catch exception on save in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a `pre_save` signal handler on a bunch of models, which write to a different database.  If something goes wrong, I'd like to abort the whole save, or failing that give a message to the user.

Based on [Display custom message from signal in the admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964958/display-custom-message-from-signal-in-the-admin), I wrote a mixin with methods like:

```
class SafeSaveMixin(object):
    def save_model(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(SafeSaveMixin, self).save_model(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            self.message_user(request, e, messages.ERROR)
```

This allows me to throw an Exception from the `pre_save` handler and show the message to the user.  The problem is, even though this winds up skipping the actual `Model.save()`, the admin console doesn't see anything, so it still reports the object as successfully saved.

If I changed the `pre_save` handler to a `post_save` handler, that would allow the base `Model.save()` to occur and at least Django would report the correct state of things, but the information I need in the other database is based on the *previous* state of the object, so I need to get to it before the save.

I've also considered stuffing the error message into the object itself in the `pre_save` and pulling it out in the mixin's `save_model()` -- but this gets more complicated in the other `ModelAdmin` save methods like `save_formset()`.

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177720/showing-custom-model-validation-exceptions-in-the-django-admin-site/39512190#39512190

Answer (score 11):

I've come up with this, which gets mixed in to the ModelAdmin class:

```
class InternalModelAdminMixin:
    """Mixin to catch all errors in the Django Admin and map them to user-visible errors."""
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        try:
            return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
        except Exception as e:
            self.message_user(request, 'Error changing model: %s' % e.msg, level=logging.ERROR)
            # This logic was cribbed from the `change_view()` handling here:
            # django/contrib/admin/options.py:response_post_save_add()
            # There might be a simpler way to do this, but it seems to do the job.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

This doesn't interfere with the actual model save process, and simply prevents the 500 error redirect. (Note this will disable the debug stacktrace handling. You could add some conditional handling to add that back in).

Comment: Any guide about how to use it?

Comment: @sami just mix it in to your class inheriting from ModelAdmin : `class MyAdmin(InternalModelAdminMixin, ModelAdmin):`

Answer (score 2):

Catching this kind of errors should not be desirable. This could mean you expose delicate information to your users, e.g. about database (if there is an IntegrityError). As this bypasses the normal error handling, you might also miss messages that inform you about errors.

If there's some check required for wrong/incomplete data a user has entered, then the way to go is to do this in `def clean(self)`

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
    field_value = cleaned_data.get('field_name')
    if not field_value:
        raise ValidationError('No value for field_name')
```

Comment: I disagree with your broad statement "should not be desirable". The default error handling of throwing a 500 error is bad UX, and for an internal company dashboard, just displaying the text of the Model error is preferable in my case. Usually that's something helpful like "model x couldn't be added because <domain reason Y>", which an admin can act on.

There are definitely plenty of cases where you wouldn't want to expose model errors like this, e.g. if you have lots of users, or non-internal users of the django admin.

Comment: What you mention about bad UX is completely wrong. Django offers a whole templating system for error handling, that includes 500 errors. You can design your server error pages as much as you like, that includes informing the user of what went wrong and how to handle the situation. Just blurting out an error message (whose text is beyond your control), and hoping users will be decent enough to let you know is bad practice. Not to mention that it's oftentimes internal users who become bad actors and use this exposed information against a company

Answer (score 1):

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    def clean(self):
        # do some validation
        # or raise ValidationError(...)
        pass   

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It usually works, and you should not do any validation in other place.

But if you use RelatedField with InlineAdmin, and validation by related instance.
Sometimes it will be wrong, Django won't render your Exceptions.

Like this question: [how to display models.full_clean() ValidationError in django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71231549/how-to-display-models-full-clean-validationerror-in-django-admin)

It confuse me about two month. And make me saw lots sources code.

Just now,I fixed it in my project(maybe...)

Hope no bug...

Answer (score 0):

We need to override `changeform_view` of your admin

In your app/admin.py

```
from .model import SomeModel # => import your model from where it exists (.model might not be valid for you)
from django.contrib import admin, messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        try:
            return super(SomeModelAdmin, self).changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
        except Exception as e:
            self.message_user(request, e, level=messages.ERROR)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)

admin.site.register(SomeModel, SomeModelAdmin)
```