# how to display models.full_clean() ValidationError in django admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
try:
    article.full_clean()
except ValidationError as e:
    # Do something based on the errors contained in e.message_dict.
    # Display them to a user, or handle them programmatically.
    pass
```

There tell us can **Display them to a user**, how to display errors in Admin?

When I do nothing:

- When Settings.py Debug = True, it always render a **ValidationError at
  /admin/xxx/xxx/xxx/change/** page.
- When Settings.py Debug = False, it always render a **HTTP 500** page.

Some code in models.py:

```
    def clean(self):
        try:
            if self.get_previous_state:
                if self.get_previous_state.state_choice == self.state_choice and \
                        self.get_previous_state.state_location == self.state_location:
                    raise ValidationError({"state_choice": f"提交的状态与当前状态冲突({self.product_entity.rfidtag.EPC_bank})"},
                                          params={'state_choice': self.state_choice})
        except Exception as e: # except the RelatedObjectDoesNotExist Exception to ValidationError
            raise ValidationError(e)

    def save(self, force_insert=True, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = None  # force_insert 具有 pk unique 限制
        self.previous_state = self.get_previous_state
        self.full_clean()
        super(ProductEntityState, self).save(force_insert=True, *args, **kwargs)
```

[sucess condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuMQa.png)

[error condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piVB1.png)

Answer (score 0):

What is the context of that code? Django will automatically show the errors for you in the admin when creating/editing the object through the admin. You don't have to manually call `full_clean()` as the auto-generated ModelForm from the admin will do so.

Comment: Wait a minute, Let me edit the question context.

Comment: When I delete and create the inline model, this exception will be triggered. But it doesn't display in admin page.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug by myself.

Because django admin just call `formsets.all_valid()` to validtion in `ModelAdmin._changeform_view()`.

`ModelAdmin._changeform_view()` uses `transaction.atomic()`.

When `formsets.all_valid()`, the froms which will be deleted didn't be commit.

Now, the previous state is the instance which will be deleted.It will not raise the `ValidationError`, the `formsets.all_valid()` will `return True`.

So `ModelAdmin._changeform_view()` will call `from.instance.save()` in foreach formsets.

This time, the previous state was be changed. So it will raise the `ValidationError`.

But `ModelAdmin._changeform_view()` didn't expect `ValidationError` in `ModelAdmin.save_related()`. it will expect by `django\core\handlers\exception.py` and call `response_for_exception()`.

I cover the `ModelAdmin._create_formsets()` and fill the `previous_state` in all `formsets.instance`.

*Notice: when you get `form`, you should watch which model not call the `model.clean()`, I use `form.changed_data` to get instance.*

Then, when `ModelAdmin._create_formsets()` call `formsets.all_valid()`. It will  `return False`, and `raise ValidationError` in your page.